# I would like to do a bar plot with two different values in the y-axis and those being dodged in the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have been looking at a bunch of answers but I could not find anything that answers my problem. 
I have the following dataset:

```
structure(list(Quail = c("28", "28", "28", "28", "29", "29", 
"29", "29", "30", "30", "30", "30", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6", "16", "16", "16", 
"16", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "18", "18", "18", "18", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "53", "53", "53", "53", "54", "54", "54", "54"
), day = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 
1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 5, 
7, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5, 7), Group = c("var", "var", 
"var", "var", "var", "var", "var", "var", "var", "var", "var", 
"var", "varL", "varL", "varL", "varL", "varL", "varL", "varL", 
"varL", "varL", "varL", "varL", "varL", "varL", "varL", "varLQ", 
"varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", 
"varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", "varQ", "varQ", 
"varQ", "varQ", "varQ", "varQ", "varQ", "varQ", "varQ", "varQ", 
"varQ", "varQ"), Equi = c(NA, 5.966699108, 2.179348795, NA, NA, 
5.47029668, 4.606832566, 4.123227924, NA, 6.200198499, 3.807239274, 
2.121998353, NA, 6.122346998, 3.161297444, 2.618107834, 2.488914738, 
NA, 5.80659996, 3.272308721, 3.012209525, 2.750162661, NA, 5.752224579, 
4.885757526, 2.515186667, NA, 5.494711674, 4.665176685, 4.017052221, 
NA, 6.165528697, 4.969614582, 2.894064483, 2.600701052, NA, 6.368332793, 
4.316409804, 6.030505124, NA, 5.173073878, 4.038968216, 2.859379995, 
NA, NA, 4.17091987, 2.916909106, NA, 5.926815246, 5.910377652, 
NA), Norm.pi = c(5.8, 3.9, 3.1, 2.5, 4.7, 2.5, 5.1, 10.1, 3.4, 
2.8, 5.4, 2.6, 4.3, 0.9, 4, 7.3, 4.1, 5.8, 1.8, 4.2, 8.5, 20.4, 
4.6, 2.1, 4.3, 11.3, 2.5, 2.9, 4, 4.4, 2.7, 2.2, 2.7, 5.6, 4.5, 
2.5, 2, 4.5, 7.1, 5.4, 2.6, 5.1, 8.3, 6.7, 2.8, 3.6, 4.6, 5.8, 
3, 3, 6.3)), row.names = c(NA, -51L), groups = structure(list(
    Quail = c("16", "16", "16", "16", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
    "17", "18", "18", "18", "18", "28", "28", "28", "28", "29", 
    "29", "29", "29", "30", "30", "30", "30", "4", "4", "4", 
    "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
    "53", "53", "53", "53", "54", "54", "54", "54", "6", "6", 
    "6", "6"), day = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 
    1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 
    5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5, 7), 
    Group = c("varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", 
    "varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", "varLQ", 
    "var", "var", "var", "var", "var", "var", "var", "var", "var", 
    "var", "var", "var", "varL", "varL", "varL", "varL", "varL", 
    "varL", "varL", "varL", "varL", "varL", "varQ", "varQ", "varQ", 
    "varQ", "varQ", "varQ", "varQ", "varQ", "varQ", "varQ", "varQ", 
    "varQ", "varL", "varL", "varL", "varL"), .rows = list(27L, 
        28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
        39L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
        13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 40L, 
        41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
        23L, 24L, 25L, 26L)), row.names = c(NA, -51L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am using ggplot as:

```
DI.pi.equi.extended %>%
  ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(x=day, y=Norm.pi), stat = "identity", fill = "red") +
    geom_bar(aes(x=day,y=Equi), stat = "identity") +

  theme(panel.grid.major =  element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 22),
        legend.direction = "vertical", legend.box = "horizontal") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,3, 5, 7, 9), limits = c(0,10))  +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . + 10)) +
  facet_grid(.~Quail + Group, scales = "free_y")
```

This is producing the following stacked plot:

[image]

What I am trying to plot is actually pi.Norm and Equi side by side, as dodged, but I could not make it work so far.

Suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Try to make a minimal example [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to convert the dataset to long format before plotting using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer`. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DI.pi.equi.extended %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(c(Equi, Norm.pi), names_to = "name", values_to = "value") %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x=day, y=value, fill = name), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Norm.pi = "red", Equi = "grey")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major =  element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 22),
        legend.direction = "vertical", legend.box = "horizontal") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,3, 5, 7, 9), limits = c(0,10))  +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . + 10)) +
  facet_grid(.~Quail + Group, scales = "free_y") 
#> Warning: Removed 15 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much @stefan! Could you please explain me this line -> tidyr::pivot_longer(c(Equi, Norm.pi), names_to = "name", values_to = "value").

Comment: @genferreri Simply put pivot_longer stacks the values in the columns "Equi" and "Norm.pi" on top of each other in a new column "value". To identify which value stems from which a pivot_longer adds a new column "name" to the df. In your case, the advantage of doing so is that the original variables become categories of just one variable which can be easily plotted. For more on pivoting see e.g. https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html#pivoting